# How do I launch Phonegap Custom Dialog on page load?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to load a Phonegap custom dialog when a page loads.  Most of the process is working (counter increments, data is saved, but no dialog launch.)

Here is my code

```
enter code here
function onConfirm(button) {
            if (button == 2){

                window.open ("http://Google.com");

            }
        }

        // Show a custom confirmation dialog
        //
        function showPrompt() {
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                                           'Do you want to search with Google?',  // message
                                           onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
                                           'Search with Google',            // title
                                           'No Thanks, Yes'          // buttonLabels
                                           );
        }

        function onBodyLoad()
        {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

            var timesRun = localStorage.getItem("TR");
            if (timesRun==null){
            timesRun=0;
            localStorage.setItem("TR", 0);}

        timesRun = parseInt(timesRun)+1;
        localStorage.setItem("TR", timesRun);
       // alert('Times Run ' + timesRun);
        if (timesRun >= 2){
            //alert('launching');
            showPrompt();

        }


    }
enter code here
```

I am using Phonegap 0.9.4.   Interestingly, if showPrompt() is called by another method (clicking a button), it works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to move the JavaScript that's listed after the "document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);" line to an actual onDeviceReady function.  In other words, add a "function onDeviceReady()" after the onBodyLoad function, and put this in it:

```
    var timesRun = localStorage.getItem("TR");
         if (timesRun==null){
         timesRun=0;
         localStorage.setItem("TR", 0);}
      timesRun = parseInt(timesRun)+1;
     localStorage.setItem("TR", timesRun);
    // alert('Times Run ' + timesRun);
     if (timesRun >= 2){
         //alert('launching');
         showPrompt();
```